# markov processes and ergodic theory

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, ergodic-theory, markov-chains, limits-and-convergence

For an ergodic Markov Chain
$$
   \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^n f(X_i) \rightarrow E_\pi[f]
$$
where $\pi$ is the invariant distribution. I am also dealing with a Markovian process (a state space model to be specific) and I have a quantity like the following:
$$
\frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^T \log p(x_t \mid x_{t-1},\theta)
$$
where the state space model that generated the data is $x(0) \sim p(x_0)$ and the transition model is $x_t \sim p(x_t \mid x_{t-1},\theta)$. Can I apply the ergodic theory in this setting? If so, what would the above sum converge to?

In general, instead of $\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T f(X_t)$ what happens if I have $\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T f(X_{t-L},\dots,X_t)$?

p.s. I asked this question in cross-validated but no answers or attention up till this point.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand exactly your question. However, it appears to me that in your case you can consider the invariant distribution $\tilde{\pi}$ of the random vectors $(X_{t},\ldots,X_{t+L}).$ Then by the Ergodic theorem the limit you are asking should be $\mathbb E_{\tilde{\pi}}(f).$

Comment: What's $\theta$? Your expression looks like it's converging to the entropy rate of the Markov chain.

Comment: $\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T f(X_{t-L},\dots,X_t)$ will converge a.s. to $E_\pi[f(X_0,\ldots,X_L)]$.

Comment: @AryehKontorovich in my application $\theta$ is unknown but for the sake of simplicity let's assume $\theta$ is a known constant. I can see the entropy connection due to p.logp term but can you give me the formal definition or a link for this term?

Comment: @JohnDawkins, well $\pi$ is the invariant distribution for $X_t$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$ right? So how do you compute the expectation $E_{\pi}[f(X_0,\dots,X_L)]$ you mentioned? Don't I need some sort of a joint $\pi$?

Comment: @user39115 Thanks for the answer. I thought about a similar thing as well. If a markov process is ergodic (ie there exists a $\pi$), does it mean such $\tilde{\pi}$ always exist?

Comment: @YBE: $E_\pi[f(X_0,X_1,\ldots,X_L)] = \sum_x\pi(x)E[f(x,X_1,\ldots,X_L)\,|\,X_0=x]$.

Comment: Take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_rate

Comment: @JohnDawkins, thanks for the explanation. That sounds reasonable.

Comment: @AryehKontorovich thanks for the link. I actually have second derivative wrt the parameter that I omitted for simplicity. I am expecting this quantity to be related to some sort of Fisher Information matrix for markovian processes. Are you aware of any such results.

Comment: Googling "markov fisher information" brings up some potentially relevant papers.